# Writing a factorial() function without distinction between 0 and other numbers

Tags: math, language-agnostic, factorial

This question has been bugging me for quite a while: is it possible to write a factorial function (in any programming language) without any `if statement` (or similar) which returns `1` when called with `0` as argument too?

Many factorial functions are something like this (Python):

```
def factorial(n):
    for x in range(1, n):
        n *= x
    return n if n > 0 else 1
```

But I don't know if it can be done without distinction between varied values of `n`... What do you think? It is not a matter of speed and optimizing, just my curiosity.

Comment: Some languages (e.g. Haskell) have lazy evaluation, others don't even have functions (e.g. Prolog has only predicates).

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/14476/34109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0! is defined as 1.

Here are the results from my code.

```
0 factorial = 1
1 factorial = 1
2 factorial = 2
3 factorial = 6
10 factorial = 3628800
```

And here's Java code with no if statement,

```java
package com.ggl.testing;

public class Factorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 0;
        System.out.println(n + " factorial = " + factorial(n));
        n = 1;
        System.out.println(n + " factorial = " + factorial(n));
        n = 2;
        System.out.println(n + " factorial = " + factorial(n));
        n = 3;
        System.out.println(n + " factorial = " + factorial(n));
        n = 10;
        System.out.println(n + " factorial = " + factorial(n));
    }

    public static long factorial(int n) {
        long product = 1L;

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            product *= (long) i;
        }

        return product;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice use of an initializer instead of an if to handle the `n = 0` case.

Comment: You could also use [`∏` (uppercase pi)](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/24909/164219)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Haskell version:

```
factorial n = product [1 .. n]
```

Not sure if that's considered cheating, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to calculate the factorial of a number with code.
The original question shows how to do it by recursion, one answer shows how to use a for loop.  The same could be achieved by a while loop.
Another answer shows the product function of an array in Haskell (similar to `prod(1:n)` in Matlab).

Another way to calculate factorial of n (including n=0) in Javascript whithout using a loop is:

```
function factorial(n){
    return (new Array(n)).join().split(",").map((x,i) => i+1).reduce((x,y) => x*y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
    def factor(n):
      fact=1
      for i in range (1,n+1):
        fact= fact*1
      return fact

    try:
      x=int(input('Input a number to find the factiorial: '))
      print(factor(x))

    except:
      print('Number should be an integer')
      x=int(input('Input a number to find the factiorial:  '))
      print(factor(x))
```

**Hope this helps you!**